# Django, filter users by group in a model foreign key

Tags: django, admin, models

I have a model for a blog post where the owner of the post is a foreign key to User. With that model any user can own a blog post. I would like to change it so that only the users in a certain group -let's call it 'bloggers'- can own a blog post object. Ideally it should appear in the admin too, I mean in the blog post admin right now the menu for 'owner' lists all the users, it should only list the ones in the 'bloggers' group.
How do I do that with Django 1.3?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use `limit_choices_to` paramether in your ForeignKey definition like this:

```
author = models.ForeignKey("auth.User", limit_choices_to={'groups__name': "bloggers"})
```

Comment: This is very helpful thank you . But what if I want limit my choices to many groups instead only one? For example, I would like to select users in either 'bloggers' group or 'viewers' group.

Comment: Simple.

    author = models.ForeignKey("auth.User", limit_choices_to={'groups__name__in': ["bloggers", "viewers"]})

Comment: do I have to make any additional import for `auth.User` above?

Comment: @pavitran `auth.User` is a known function and don't need  to import in `models.py` file. I test and work perfect.